# In "Hardcore Henry", why was Henry's battery low when he first woke up?

Tags: cyborg, hardcore-henry

I get that there was an awful lot of manipulation happening in *Hardcore Henry*, but at the very beginning of the movie, we learn that Henry has only about 15-20 minutes of charge left on his battery. We have watched him in near-realtime for the movie up until this point.

Let's be generous and round the time from awakening to battery shutdown to an hour. Was the battery only good for an hour or was Henry awoken with a depleted battery? When he swaps it out, the source presumably didn't recharge the battery every hour, and yet about an hour later in the movie he swaps it out yet again. My best guess is that a human using the battery as a pacemaker will end up using less power, while a cyborg like Henry will use vastly more power and require more frequent charging. That fits in with the second battery swap.

But then either there was a plan for an army of men with only an hour of fighting power (which seems stupid) or Henry was just continually swapping out a non-full battery for another non-full battery, which seems a questionable plan from Alan's perspective. So what is going on here with the batteries?

Comment: How is the film? I read some positive opinions, but not sure if I want to pump it up my watch list.

Comment: @Gallifreyan: It's an FPS video-game quickplay turned into a film. Fascinating for the spectacle, but it starts to wear thin by the end.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots  -  the director made a music video for Weeknd's [_False Alarm_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CW5oGRx9CLM). Looks nice indeed!

Comment: @Gallifreyan it's a shtick, but they play it fair. The perspective means the director can't use many of the usual cheats of the biz and must instead use completely different cheats. It starts slow and gradually gets faster and crazier, training you to be comfortable with the new perspective. It's hyper violent and a remarkably good storyline. I saw it opening night and have watched it probably four times since. I would say that if you love violent 80s action movies, or the fight sequence between the Bride and the room full of Asian ninjas in Kill Bill (a movie I dislike), you'll enjoy this.

Comment: I think the comments here should have spoiler tags applied to them. The question is OK.

Comment: @MrLister I tried to be vague in the question and comment as well, not sure where the spoilers were.